# Cannot View contents in ios 7 pickerview

Tags: ios7, ios4, uipickerview

I have a project already written in IOS 4.3 which I want to upgrade to IOS 7. Everything is working fine. I have a problem (bug) when I click on a textfield it represents pickerview which retrieves data from database (which is actually retrieving) but is not being displayed on the pickerview.

```
[occasionActionSheetObj addSubview:occasionPickerObj];
[occasionActionSheetObj addSubview:doneButton];
[occasionActionSheetObj addSubview:addButton];
[occasionActionSheetObj addSubview:cancelButton];
[occasionActionSheetObj addSubview:clearButton];
[occasionActionSheetObj addSubview:deleteButton];
[occasionActionSheetObj showInView:self.view];   
[occasionActionSheetObj sendSubviewToBack:occasionPickerObj];
```

on executing following code it also sets number of errors

```
[occasionActionSheetObj showInView:self.view];
```

kindly help me with displaying contents on the picker and action sheet
error displayed is:

> Aug  7 18:46:07 Amit.local Anniversary Tracker[5148] :
>   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> Aug  7 18:46:07 Amit.local Anniversary Tracker[5148] :
>   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a
>   serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
>   invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation
>   of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> Aug  7 18:46:07 Amit.local Anniversary Tracker[5148] :
>   CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error.
>   This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context 
>   and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system
>   stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this
>   problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> Aug  7 18:46:07 Amit.local Anniversary Tracker[5148] :
>   CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error.
>   This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context 
>   and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system
>   stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this
>   problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> Aug  7 18:46:07 Amit.local Anniversary Tracker[5148] :
>   CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This
>   application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is
>   thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and
>   reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It
>   will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> Aug  7 18:46:07 Amit.local Anniversary Tracker[5148] :
>   CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This
>   application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is
>   thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and
>   reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It
>   will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> Aug  7 18:46:07 Amit.local Anniversary Tracker[5148] :
>   CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error.
>   This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context 
>   and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system
>   stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this
>   problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update. (lldb)

Comment: yes, you cannot add subviews to e.g. a `UIPickerView`, `UIActionSheet` or `UIAlertView` instances in iOS7+.

Comment: ok. What can be done in that case???

Comment: the issue of picker not being displayed on actionsheet is cleared. all i had to do was remove the statement [occasionActionSheetObj sendSubviewToBack:occasionPickerObj]; but the errors still do exists. can you help me with removing those above fatal errors